# Lock screen orientation (Android)

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I'm writing an android application that uses tabs with different contents (activities).
In one of these activities, I would like to lock the screen orientation to "Landscape"-mode,
but in the other activities, I want the normal orientation (according to sensor).

What I'm doing now is that I'm calling

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

when I switch to the landscape mode activity, and

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

when I switch back to the other activities. However, this doesn't seem to work,
the whole application locks up. What is the normal approach to this problem?

Comment: The "Possible Duplicate" link is **not** a duplicate question to this one.  This question is asking how to **lock the orientation** so that it cannot change from landscape.  The linked question is asking how to **prevent application restarts** when the orientation does change.

Comment: This seems to be what you want: Call `Screen.lockOrientation(this)` and later `Screen.unlockOrientation(this)` from https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/Screen.java

Comment: Just a caution though, if you are using        inline ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT, this is not allowed below 4.3 . You can then use above or ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT

Comment: For future readers, @caw 's method is not an accessible method from within the context of a regular Android application.

Comment: @LoungeKatt No, it’s not, but I did link to the implementation, didn’t I? Anyway, I just saw that the link is not valid anymore. Here’s an updated link to the source for both `Screen.lockOrientation` and `Screen.unlockOrientation`: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Commons/blob/f220021846f66917d56d465c7150bce9b585c08d/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/commons/Screen.java#L48

Comment: @caw As you have already noticed, the link was broken when making the comment. It seems like a rather extravagant solution, so it seemed good to point out that it wasn't part of the API.

Comment: @LoungeKatt Sure. But what exactly is extravagant about it? It’s quite a pragmatic approach: It detects the current orientation (which has been determined automatically by the OS) and then sets that orientation explicitly in order to lock it.

Comment: @caw This isn't really the place to explain it. No need to hijack someone else's answer to get feedback on your own.

Answer (score 259):

In the Manifest, you can set the screenOrientation to landscape. It would look something like this in the XML:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
...
</activity>
```

Where `MyActivity` is the one you want to stay in landscape.

The `android:configChanges=...` line prevents `onResume()`, `onPause()` from being called when the screen is rotated. Without this line, the rotation will stay as you requested but the calls will still be made.

Note: `keyboardHidden` and `orientation` are required for < Android 3.2 (API level 13), and all three options are required 3.2 or above, not just `orientation`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work; am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm yeah you're right that doesn't seem to work if the Activity is running inside a TabHost. I think you might have the right idea using `setRequestedOrientation`, but try putting the call in `onResume`, *not* `onCreate`, and in the non-landscape Activity use `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` instead of `SENSOR`. My emulator bugged out too with sensor, but unspecified worked

Comment: is there any way to defined orientation for service..basically I write an LiveWallpaper service...where need to restrict device orientation.

Comment: this rotates my screen only clockwise, how can I rotate it anticlockwise?

Comment: This method has so many disadvantages to it and is considered an anti-pattern since 2016. Better to learn the Activity lifecycle, particularly _what_ events call when you rotate the device. I'm currently looking for a solution to this however.

Answer (score 65):

I had a similar problem.

When I entered

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

In the manifest file this caused that activity to display in landscape.  However when I returned to previous activities they displayed in lanscape even though they were set to portrait.  However by adding

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

immediately after the OnCreate section of the target activity resolved the problem.  So I now use both methods.

Comment: Just a caution though, if you are using ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT, this is not allowed below 4.3 . You can then use above or ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT

Comment: Warning: Using setRequestedOrientation() will cause the Activity to restart, triggering onResume etc twice. Add this to your manifest for every activity where you do this to avoid it: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 40):

inside the Android manifest file of your project, find the activity declaration of whose you want to fix the orientation and add the following piece of code ,

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

for landscape orientation and for portrait add the following code,

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```