# Android screen orientation challenge

Tags: android, orientation

I want to do something somewhat unique regarding screen orientation:

(1) When the activity starts, if the device is in Portrait orientation, I want to display a view that asks the user to please rotate the device into Landscape orientation.

(2) Once the device is rotated, I want to show a new view which contains the main UI for the activity.

(3) If the user rotates the device further afterward, I want to either retain the orientation selected in step 2 or allow only the reverse-landscape orientation, and disallow portrait orientation.

So far I'm able to do steps 1 and 2, but I can't figure out how to accomplish step 3. I thought I could set my requested orientation to either Landscape or Sensor Landscape, but that doesn't work (in the first case I get an upside-down screen depending on the original orientation and in the second I always get portrait orientation for some reason).

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Or [Lock screen orientation (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android)