# Android support portrait only in mobile

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

Home to make android application to run in portrait mode only in mobile, where as in tablet it allow both  portrait and landscape orientation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180764/how-do-i-lock-screen-orientation-for-phone-but-not-for-tablet-android

Answer (score 1):

First check in your activity or slpash screen that the application must be run in which device.

Check the below code to your mainActivity or splash screen.

```
Intent intent;
if (isTablet(DeciderActivity.this)) 
{
   // for Tablet
   intent = new Intent(this, TabletSplashActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
} 
else 
{
  // for Phone
  intent = new Intent(this, PhoneSplashActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Please declare the isTablet method

```
public static boolean isTablet() {

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        float yInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi;
        float xInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
        double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(xInches * xInches + yInches * yInches);

        if (diagonalInches >= 7) {
                // 7inch device or bigger
                return true;
            } else {
                // smaller device
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I hope this will work for you, it was working fine with my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, set this for all your activities:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Let me explain:

- With `android:configChanges="orientation"` you tell Android that you will be responsible of the changes of orientation.
- `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` you set the default orientation mode.

You can call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` ine the onCreate method of your Activity if the device is a phone. To determine if the device is a phone or a tablet, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet).