# Screen Orientation turned off

Tags: android, screen-orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock screen orientation (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android)

I want when my screen orientates, my screen stays vertical, because now my xml file looks so bad. So I want my screen continues to look like it was, not to orientate. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your activity

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep your `Activity` in portrait mode you can add screen orientation in your XML.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your activity's manifest:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```