# how to force an Android app into landscape only or portrait only?

Tags: android

how to force an app into landscape only or portrait only? I want to app locked into the orientation of user choices.

Thanks a lot for sharing!!

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 <activity android:name="Intro"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.gmaninc.package.INTRO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

one of the following in each activity in the manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps to achieve what you wanted to do..

1. Open Android Manifest file.
2. Set Orientation to Portrait or Landscape

that's it..