# Amazon FireTV Web App to Android WebView

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webview

I am new to Android coding, I have done some coding in the past mainly HTML, Visual Basic, JSON, etc. However, I have successfully created a WebView App using Android Studio.  I have it looking exactly how I want but I have 2 problems.  I have the WebView app loading my Amazon Fire TV Web App HTML ( https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/outinthebg/outinthebg_firetv/index.html )

Problem 1- The BIG One
When I click on a video to play it the screen goes black, a white circle spins as if its going to play and then nothing happens. It just keeps spinning. I have tried several variations of code through searching on google but all posts were from 2012 and 2013.

Problem 2- I would love for the app to automatically load in Landscape no matter the orientation of the device, stay in landscape and never be able to go to portrait view.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To force an orientation, you just need to edit the manifest:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668477/how-to-force-an-android-app-into-landscape-only-or-portrait-only

Comment: Thank you, that will help with the smaller issue.

Comment: You might want to review the access logs for the bucket.  Also, please try to limit questions to a single question.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how to access the logs. I am new to android studio.