# App changes screen orientation from landscape to portrait after unlocking the phone

Tags: android

I build an app with screen orientation set to landscape in the manifest.

in activity;

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

I just realize when I lock my phone and then unlock it, orientation changed to portrait.

I try calling the

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

In onResume and onStart but It didn't work. Screen orientation is always portrait after unlocking the phone. What can I do for solving this, any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android

Comment: I think this is a different problem @SudheerChowdarySirimalla