# Sensor landscape allows orientation issue in Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

When set to landscape the screen is fixed but when set to sensor landscape it can rotate to any orientation. I don't understand why it wont lock to landscape and reverse landscape as desired.

It is set in the manifest file.

I get no errors or warnings.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! 
The compiler had cached a previous version of the manifest file instead of building it every time like the APK. 
To fix it I deleted the generated files and folders like bin and gen etc.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675801/1928342) answer...
(check if u put the screenOrientation argument on the right activity)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, it is set in the manifest file so this isn't the issue.