# Lock screen rotation

Tags: java, android

I am using

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);`

to lock my app screen(programmatically), but in some devices if i call this method in landscape it rotate to portrait instead of locking the screen.

Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: Do it in your manifest if it's *always* supposed to be that way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android

Comment: but i want that my app will support both landscape and portrait but i some cases to lock it(pressing a button for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
<activity
            android:name="Your activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `XML` file for your `Activity,`add `android:orientation="horizontal"`