# Code working in portrait mode, not in landscape mode(which is blocked) (getActivity() null pointer)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm in work fighting with one bug which I can't google/solve.
Our app has blocked landscape mode (it never change orientation), but while testing it I saw it crashes while being on different rotation (but still on portrait mode).
Code working good well always on portrait mode.
We have one activity which have ViewPager (with 3 fragments). App is crashing while trying to get getActivity (because its nullpointer).

In activity I'm opening method from fragment to fill some radio buttons information in runOnUiThread method:

```
@Override
public void onGetPlayerSuccess(HandballPlayerTO player) {
    handballPlayer = player;

    if (handballPlayer.gethandballDictionaryFacts() == null) {
        handballPlayer.sethandballDictionaryFacts(new ArrayList<HandballDictionaryFactTO>());
    }

    setRefreshing(false);
    injuriesAdapter.setInjuries(player.getHandballInjuryTOS());
    injuriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    setListAppendixViews();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            demographicFragment.fillFields();
            careerFragment.fillFields();
            lifestyleFragment.fillFields();
        }
    });
}
```

Inside fillField()

I'm using following method:

```
HandballPlayerTO player = ((PlayerActivity) getActivity()).getPlayerTO();
```

which crashes app, while I am trying just to send the player through arguments it doesn't have correct information.

I'm totally confused because I never heard about differences in running the code in landscape mode/portrait mode.

Both have same code, same XML. I don't change the orientation. I tried to run it from beginning on landscape (and it crashes) and change orientation from portrait mode before opening activity (and it crashes too).

I only can find solution to null pointer problem for issues on changing orientation etc.

Comment: make sure this happens after onAttach in fragment. If it happens before or that fragment is not attached to activity this will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution which helped:
[Lock screen orientation (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android)

I changed manifest file, add screenOrientation to portrait mode.
Previously we used flags while starting new activity.