# Can't lock landscape on exported Unity Project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've googled around and tried all of these:

Setting landscape within Unity before exporting

Setting `android:screenOrientation:"landscape"` on Android Manifest, in both the exported project and the Parent project (since the exported project will then be compiled as a library for yet another project)

Using `setRequestedOrientation` at Runtime in the parent project

But it still seems to go Full Sensor. I just want it to lock at landscape, but nothing seems to work so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you creating build from Unity3D?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity for the landscape rotation, leave the Autorotation turned on, and unmark the portrait one.
I have pasted the example screenshot of the sample unity project.

[image: Screenshot of the example]